# How to get max datetimestamp of a user by passing list of userIds in spring data native query or by repository

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot, group-by, spring-data

I have a table **transactions** where all transactions details will be stored as below,

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | merchant_id | amount              | requested_timestamp |
+----+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |           5 | 10                  | 2020-06-02 01:47:47 |
|  2 |           5 | 20                  | 2020-06-02 05:00:14 |
|  3 |      744900 | 30                  | 2020-06-02 05:00:27 |
|  4 |      154427 | 100                 | 2020-06-02 05:01:03 |
|  5 |      504968 | 15                  | 2020-06-02 05:01:26 |
|  6 |       75703 | 20                  | 2020-06-02 05:01:31 |
|  7 |      732228 | 50                  | 2020-06-02 05:01:59 |
|  8 |      506342 | 25                  | 2020-06-02 05:02:17 |
|  9 |      504968 | 40                  | 2020-06-02 05:02:36 |
| 10 |      732228 | 30                  | 2020-06-02 05:02:50 |
+----+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

i want to find max timestamp of each merchant in one hit like passing **list of merchantId's** to a query.
i have tried using spring data as below

```
List<Transactions> findTop1ByMerchantIdInOrderByIdAsc(List<Integer> merchantIds);
```

but its not giving max timestamp.

i tried as below

```
@Query("select merchantId,max(requestedTimestamp) from Transactions where merchantId in ?1")
      List<Object[]> getLastTxnsOfAllMerchants(List<Integer> merchantIds);
```

this give exception.

even with **Native query** also my problem will be solved as below

```
 @Query(nativeQuery=true,value="select merchant_id,max(requested_timestamp) from transactions where merchant_id in ?1")
   List<Object[]> getLastTxnsOfAllMerchants(List<Integer> merchantIds);
```

this also gives exception

please help me with this thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run query like

```
SELECT merchant_id, MAX(requested_timestamp) FROM transactions
GROUP BY merchant_id;
```

Or if you want specific merchants

```
SELECT merchant_id, MAX(requested_timestamp) FROM transactions
WHERE merchant_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY merchant_id;
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks but i do not want Group by in this. with out group by is it possible ?

Comment: then you can skip group by and do one query for each merchant; SELECT merchant_id, MAX(requested_timestamp) FROM transactions
WHERE merchant_id = 1;